# How to sort contacts alphabetically while using SwiftAddressBook?

Tags: ios, swift

I take it there is no proper documentation for [SwiftAddressBook](https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook) or maybe I haven't found it but after an hour of blind arrows I think I have finally found a way to sort the contacts according to their first names and it still won't even compile. Here is the code

```
let sources = swiftAddressBook?.allSources
self.people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(sources, ordering: SwiftAddressBookOrdering.firstName)
```

It says **_?? is not convertible to _??**

Anyone knows how to do this? Or should I be even using this?

**EDIT**

I tried this -

```
let sources = swiftAddressBook?.defaultSource
self.people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(sources!, ordering: SwiftAddressBookOrdering.firstName)
```

and it worked but it showed only a very few contacts

Answer (score 1):

```
let sources = swiftAddressBook?.allSources as [SwiftAddressBookSource]?
            if let srcs = sources{
                for source in srcs
                {
                    self.people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(source, ordering: SwiftAddressBookOrdering.firstName)
                }
            }
```

Comment: i am on top of the world :D